# Conversion to Integer with Positive or Negative

Tags: string, matlab

In MATLAB I have a 1 X 20 column vector of string data in a file name A.txt.

```
%Input in A.txt:
60N
61N
50S
51S
```

Objective: to read the column of data as integers and represent N

as positive and S as negative.

So the output would be:

```
 60
 61
-50
-51
```

I have researched other posts, apply str2num double. I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Do all your strings have 3-char length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data is composed like in your example, you can try this:

```
[nums, directions] = textread('test.txt', '%d%s'); %# Read data from file
signs = ones(size(directions));                    %# Assume signs are positive
signs(strcmp(directions, 'S')) = -1;               %# Replace 'S' with negatives
result = nums(:) .* signs(:)                       %# Calculate result
```